# UriBuilder incorrectly encoding Query Parameters value?

Tags: java, encoding, jax-rs, query-string

Lets consider the following code sample where a path and single parameter are encoded...

Parameter name:  "param"

Parameter value: "foo/bar?aaa=bbb&ccc=ddd" (happens to be a url with query parameters)

```
   String test = UriBuilder.fromPath("https://dummy.com").
               queryParam("param", "foo/bar?aaa=bbb&ccc=ddd").
               build().toURL().toString();
```

The encoded URL string returned is:

```
 "https://dummy.com?param=foo/bar?aaa%3Dbbb&ccc%3Dddd"
```

Is this correct ?

Should not the character "&" (and may be even "?") be encoded in the parameter value string ?

Would not the URL produced be interpreted as follow:

One first parameter, name="param", value = "ar?aaa%3Dbbb" followed by a second parameter, name="ccc%3Dddd", without value.

Comment: UriBuilder does not belong to the standard Java API AFAIK , which is its package ?

Comment: It is in JAX-RS (Java API for RESTful Web Services)

Answer (score 1):

Your initial call to "fromPath" should probably be "fromUri".  That said...

> Is this correct ?

No, it does not look like correct output.

> Should not the character "&" (and may
>   be even "?") be encoded in the
>   parameter value string ?

Yes, it should be.

> Would not the URL produced be
>   interpreted as follow:
>
> One first parameter, name="param",
>   value = "ar?aaa%3Dbbb" followed by a
>   second parameter, name="ccc%3Dddd",
>   without value.

The first parameter would be "foo/bar?aaa=bbb", but yes, you're interpreting properly.  This looks like a bug in your javax.ws.rs.core provider.

Comment: It actually was a Jersey bug (http://java.net/jira/browse/JERSEY-533?focusedCommentId=15079&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#action_15079)